# How to escape string in TEC printer code?

Tags: escaping, thermal-printer

I'm working with TEC Toshiba printer.
I know I cannot print directly many special chars like `{}();:` and so on, how can I escape these chars?

I think the solution is valud for all TEC printers, but now I'm working with this model: Toshiba B-EV4-G

Comment: Is it a matter of application system environment or configuration, not printer? For example, are you trying to print from a web browser? And it is difficult to get advice and answers without detailed information on the model number of the printer, the OS and programming language used, the connection between the application and the printer, the device driver, etc.

Comment: It is a matter of language syntax. This markup language for toshiba printers uses special chars like `{|}` as separator and I need to know how to escape them.

Comment: These materials may be helpful. [TOSHIBA Printer Driver Operation Manual](https://business.toshiba.com/downloads/KB/f1Ulds/15461/Printer_Driver_V742M0_17th.pdf), [TOSHIBA B-EV4 Series External Equipment Interface Specification](http://www.printmark.de/downloads/prog_manuals/Prog_handb_B-EV4.pdf), [TOSHIBA B-EV4 Printer Setting Tool Operating Specification](https://usermanual.wiki/Document/BEV4SetTool7th.1089800287/view)